# How/why does the Community mod close questions?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, moderators, users

[This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/114877/ringed-planet-reality-check-on-ring-shadow-visuals) about reality-checking the shadows of a ringed planet was placed in the reopen review queue after an edit was made. While the edit appears to be insufficient to separate the two questions, I noticed that the question was put on hold with just two votes: Molot and the Community diamond moderator.

I've seen the Community mod a number of times and understood it to be something of a helper or cleanup "user." Why does it have the power to vote to close and when does it choose to do so?

Answer (score 14):

That's the user themselves closing the question as a duplicate. When someone votes to close as a duplicate the user is asked whether they agree - and when they do the community user with his "mod powers" closes the question instantly on behalf of the user who potentially doesn't have any special close votes.

See also: [New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/352819). If you hover over the community vote you can see the text:

> This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote.

Comment: Interesting! That makes sense, I had wondered that myself a few times.

Comment: To be honest, I'm surprised. I cast my vote  because at  the time I believed these are duplicates, but I expected OP to use "different, explain why"  rather than "agreed".

Comment: @Mołot Well, sometimes people accept that others have already asked the same question and that there already is an answer for their problem. Good job on finding that duplicate and helping the OP so fast!